# Upgrade Magento V2.3.3-p1 to Magento V2.4.3 issue

Tags: upgrade, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.3

I am trying to upgrade the Magento V2.3.3-p1 to Magento V2.4.3 after upgraded **php V7.4** and **Composer V2.x**. When using `composer update` getting below error.

> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3].
> - paypal/module-braintree 4.2.4 requires paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.4 -> satisfiable by
> paypal/module-braintree-core[4.2.4].
> - paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.4 conflicts with magento/module-braintree * (gene/module-braintree 3.5.0 replaces
> magento/module-braintree 100.*.*).
> - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 requires paypal/module-braintree 4.2.4 -> satisfiable by
> paypal/module-braintree[4.2.4].
> - Root composer.json requires gene/module-braintree ^3.5.0 -> satisfiable by gene/module-braintree[3.5.0].

and my **composer.json** file is

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.3",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "shipperhq/module-shipper": "^20.45",
        "shipperhq/module-logger": "^20.5",
        "cloudflare/cloudflare-magento": "^1.1",
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "^1.0",
        "shipperhq/module-address-autocomplete": "^20.3",
        "gene/module-braintree": "^3.5.0",
        "mirasvit/module-helpdesk": "*",
        "mirasvit/module-affiliate": "*",
        "mirasvit/module-credit": "*",
        "swissup/module-marketplace": "^1.8",
        "swissup/recaptcha": "^1.3",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~9",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `“gene/module-braintree”: “^3.5.0"` line in composer file is solved the issue. The reason is that `paypal/module-braintree-core` is included by default and is actually a fork of the Gene Commerce module.

The Paypal module has this in the composer file :

```
"conflict": {
    "magento/module-braintree": "*",
    "gene/module-braintree": "*"
}
```

So it’s forcing the error.

Thanks to @barnyshergold in Magento Community Engineering.

Comment: thank you @Bojjaiah useful this post for me.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading did you happen to have a related issue with viewing products are you removed gene/module-braintree?

Now when I view a product I get the following error.  Haven't found a solution yet, but feels related to removal of gene/module-braintree.  That is my current theory anyway.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class PayPal\Subscription\Model\Config\Source\Subscription\PriceType does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class PayPal\Subscription\Model\Config\Source\Subscription\PriceType does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36]
#5 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:642]
#6 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php:824]
#7 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor->getSource() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:696]
#8 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->setupAttributeMeta() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#9 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#10 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#11 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav/Interceptor.php:59]
#12 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav\Interceptor->setupAttributeMeta() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:408]
#13 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->getContainerChildren() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav/Interceptor.php:41]
#14 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav\Interceptor->getContainerChildren() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:381]
#15 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->addContainerChildren() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav/Interceptor.php:32]
#16 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav\Interceptor->addContainerChildren() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:356]
#17 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->getAttributesMeta() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:316]
#18 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->modifyMeta() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav/Interceptor.php:23]
#19 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav\Interceptor->modifyMeta() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/ProductDataProvider.php:73]
#20 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider->getMeta() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:330]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:231]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:140]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:103]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:93]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:365]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:68]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:65]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:271]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:896]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:293]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]
#34 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:23]
#35 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php:82]
#36 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#37 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#38 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#39 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php:23]
#40 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#41 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:151]
#42 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#43 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#44 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#45 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#46 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#47 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php:32]
#48 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:245]
#49 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:212]
#50 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:147]
#51 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#52 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#53 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#54 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#55 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#56 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#57 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#58 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
</pre>
```

Comment: Working fine, I'm not got this type of error.